# Docker: run script : ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Hello I'm trying to run a script to just start my yarn dev after my postgres is connected:

```
until psql -c '\l'; do
  echo >&2 "$(date +%Y%m%dt%H%M%S) Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done
echo >&2 "$(date +%Y%m%dt%H%M%S) Postgres is up - executing command"

exec ${@}
```

**docker file:**

```
    #building code
    FROM node:lts-alpine

    RUN mkdir -p /home/node/api && chown -R node:node /home/node/api

    WORKDIR /home/node/api

    COPY ormconfig.json .env package.json yarn.* ./

    USER node

    RUN yarn

    COPY --chown=node:node . .

    RUN apk add --no-cache openssl

    COPY wait-pg.sh ./
    RUN chmod +x /wait-pg.sh
    ENTRYPOINT ["/wait-pg.sh"]

    EXPOSE 4000

    CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

**docker compose:**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db-pg:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: db-pg
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT}:5432'
    environment:
      ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'no'
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ci-postgres-data:/data

  ci-api:
    build: .
    container_name: ci-api
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/api
      - /home/node/api/node_modules
    ports:
      - '${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}'
    depends_on:
      - db-pg
    command: ['./wait-pg.sh', 'yarn', 'dev']
    logging:
      driver: 'json-file'
      options:
        max-size: '10m'
        max-file: '5'

volumes:
  ci-postgres-data:
```

and  get this error:

> ---> Running in c5add5098b70 ERROR: Unable to lock database:
>   Permission denied ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission
>   denied ERROR: Service 'ci-api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh
>   -c apk add --no-cache openssl' returned a non-zero code: 99

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the node user you are trying to use does not have permissions to run the command. 
Move the user definition to after the commands,  something like this:

```
  #building code
    FROM node:lts-alpine

    RUN mkdir -p /home/node/api && chown -R node:node /home/node/api
    WORKDIR /home/node/api
    COPY ormconfig.json .env package.json yarn.* ./

    RUN yarn
    COPY --chown=node:node . .
    RUN apk add --no-cache openssl
    COPY wait-pg.sh .
    RUN chmod +x ./wait-pg.sh

    USER node



    ENTRYPOINT ["./wait-pg.sh"]
    EXPOSE 4000
    CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

Comment: i got this error : chmod: /wait-pg.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: You are copying the file to ./ but trying to run it from / (those are two different directories, the dot makes a big difference) Try chmod on ./wait-pg Note that you may change your entry point too)

Comment: can u helpme with this? i believe i don't need to run the docker file, but through the docker-composite could you help me how it would look?

Comment: Fix your docker file first and then post any errors you may get running docker-compose. Looking at your compose file, it looks fine except the second volume in the node app which I do not think you need since it is a child of your first volume. Here is a simple docker-compose that connects a node js app to multiple DBs if it helps https://bitbucket.org/Bolbeck/nodewithmultidb/src/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: i couldn't understand how to solve my dockerfile, i don't understand much about linux: / can u help me?

Comment: See updated answer and see if that fixes the chmod error